# Where is the error in this query? (sql-ex.ru exercise 25)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to solve [Exercise 25](http://www.sql-ex.ru/exercises/index.php?act=learn&LN=25) from sql-ex.ru:

> The database scheme consists of four tables:
>
> - Product(maker, model, type)
> - PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
> - Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
> - Printer(code, model, color, type, price)
>
> Find the printer makers also producing PCs with the lowest RAM capacity and the highest processor speed of all PCs having the lowest RAM capacity. 
>   Result set: maker.

I can't see why the following query does not produce the desired result on the second checking database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product.maker
FROM product
RIGHT JOIN printer ON printer.model = product.model
WHERE product.maker IN(
    SELECT product.maker
    FROM product
    RIGHT JOIN pc ON pc.model = product.model
    WHERE pc.ram = (SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc)
    AND pc.speed = (
        SELECT MAX(t.speed)
        FROM (SELECT speed FROM pc WHERE ram = (SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc)) AS t
    )
)
```

The error is as follows:

```
Wrong
Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed test on second, checking database
* Wrong number of records (less by 1)
```

Why does it fail to pick exactly 1 maker?

Comment: what is happening when you change RIGHT JOINs into INNER JOIN

Comment: @ErayBalkanli Tried it and got the same error, as expected, since the product table contains all models from the pc table, so INNER and RIGHT joins are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where is the error in your query, but you can use something like this:

WITH t AS
(
     SELECT * FROM PC c WHERE c.ram = (SELECT MIN(ram) FROM PC)
)
SELECT DISTINCT a.maker 
FROM Product a WHERE a.type = 'PC' AND a.maker IN
(
     SELECT b.maker FROM Product b WHERE b.type = 'Printer'
) AND a.model IN 
(
     SELECT model FROM t WHERE speed = (SELECT MAX(speed) FROM t)
)

Comment: @Eric What are you talking about?

Comment: Your query will not run in MySQL.  Don't post answer that doesn't work.  It's useless to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution to this problem:

```
WITH CTE_Product AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Maker
    FROM
        Product
    WHERE
        Type = 'PC'
    AND
        Maker IN (SELECT Maker FROM Product WHERE Type = 'Printer')
)

select c.maker from CTE_Product C
inner join
(
select distinct maker from product inner join PC on product.model=pc.model 
where type='PC'and  
pc.speed in 
          (select max(speed) 
           from pc 
           where ram=
                     (select min(ram)from pc)
           )
 and pc.ram=
             (select min(ram)
              from pc)
) A on A.maker = C.maker
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker
  FROM Product
 WHERE TYPE = 'Printer'

 INTERSECT

SELECT DISTINCT maker
  FROM Product AS p
    INNER JOIN PC as pc
    ON p.model = pc.model
    WHERE
      type = 'PC'
      AND (pc.ram = ALL (SELECT MIN(ram) FROM PC))
        AND (pc.speed = (SELECT MAX(speed) FROM PC WHERE ram = (SELECT MIN(ram) FROM PC )))
```